# Javascript file does not loaded in asp.net in IE

Tags: asp.net, json, internet-explorer, devexpress

I have asp.net usercontrol and I should implement simple client functionality - send two numbers to the server. I use devexpress, which allow me to send only one string on callback to server. So I don't want to invent a wheel and just use JSON.stringify method.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js"></script>
<cc1:Button runat="server" ClientSideEvents-Click="
function(s,e)
{
    cbpanelCtrl.PerformCallback(JSON.stringify({width: 800, height: 600}));
}" 
Text="Reload" 
AutoPostBack="false">
```

Everything works fine in firefox but error raised in IE: **Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined**
Why? How should I load script properly?

Comment: did you try something like this : `ClientSideEvents-Click="javascript: <your_code> ..."` ?

Comment: It's devexpress format of client code. This is definitely not a problem.

Comment: which IE version are you using? Is javascript disabled in your IE?

Comment: IE9, ofc javascript is enabled

Comment: Try saving json2.js file locally and load the local script and run ...

Comment: no, it should be remote script

Comment: what add-ons are there on your IE browser? DivX,LLC?

Comment: Also try running in release mode if possible ...

Comment: I use IE only while developing, so no additional add-ons installed, only default ones. Release mode did not help (I would be very surprised if it could help here)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9045/discussion-between-harshith-j-v-and-vitalii-korsakov)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I just use wrong library. I used old version which is not supported by IE. Everyting fine with recent version here http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js

Answer (score 0):

Check whether or not the **JSON** object is available in the current context in the problematic browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(typeof(JSON));
    alert(typeof(JSON.stringify));
</script>
```

Comment: I think error message "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined" is quite descriptive. If object is undefined, of course typeof(JSON) will be undefined as well

Comment: I mean check whether or not the issue is the specifics of the cc1:Button control or IE browser only.